# Use of Sinc in pyomo

Tags: function, trigonometry, pyomo

I have constructed using mathematica a function of x and y as a sum of sincs, which are defined as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function. I have to send this to a coworker who uses pyomo. However, Pyomo doesn't understand this. I have tried everything in Mathematica to reproduce the function without using sinc, but I haven't obtained satisfactory results. The only alternative that I see is to tell my coworker to implement the sinc function in pyomo instead.

The only posts that I have found in which this is discussed are: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/JsF8ISkt-rI

and

https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/323

However, as they say, the provided solutions aren't good. Please bear in mind that I have never used pyomo and I am unaware of it's internal workings.

Now I will show the first terms of the function constructed using mathematica that I need to send to my coworker:

```js
2.16445 Sinc[3.49066 (-10. + v)] Sinc[3.49066 (-10. + w)] + 
 1.99878 Sinc[3.49066 (-9.1 + v)] Sinc[3.49066 (-10. + w)] + 
 1.64689 Sinc[3.49066 (-8.2 + v)] Sinc[3.49066 (-10. + w)] + 
 1.12779 Sinc[3.49066 (-7.3 + v)] Sinc[3.49066 (-10. + w)]
```

being v and w x and y respectively.

I need to know how to define the Sinc function in pyomo so that it can understand the code shown above.

Comment: Does pyomo have bessel functions? If so you could use them, as the (unnormalised) sinc function is the first bessel function, j0.

Comment: It is very unlikely that Pyomo has sinc function. Have you thought about using the Taylor's theorem if approximation is not an issue?

Comment: Also, are `v`, `w`, `x` and `y` decisions variables in the Pyomo model, or some are only parameters?

Comment: For dmuir: I don't know if Pyomo has them, but it looks like a nice alternative. For W. Brunelle: We have looked and it doesn't seem like so. I am trying now to define my own sinc in Python